# node jitsu Error: Cannot find module 'xmlhttprequest'

Tags: node.js, nodejitsu

Trying to deploy a node.js app to nodejitsu.
fails to deploy with the Error: Cannot find module 'xmlhttprequest'.
xmlhttprequest is local node_modules and package.json.
gitignore is not excluding node_modules.

App works properly when run locally but won't deploy.

Comment: Not much details we have got here but i have a small hunch in this regard, If you're on linux and not under root user account then try to execute your node script with `sudo`